# Rendering a variable number of ngGrids after page load

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app. I load a spreadsheet into it, do some javascript, and then I want to render a variable number of tabs each with an ngGrid depending on whats in the spreadsheet I load into the page. Therefore I have to render the html with the angular markup after app initialization.

I tried putting the part of the page with the tabbed ngGrids in a nested controller and not doing app.controller('SubController', SubController); until after the spreadsheet is parsed. However, the controller is getting initialized at page load.

My initialization code looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngGrid', 'percentage', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload', 'vr.directives.slider']);
```

What do I do to make the nested controller not initialize at page load time?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious in hindsight, was just to use a ngRepeat directive.

```
    <div id="x-{{ $index }}" class="col-sm-12" data-ng-repeat="Grid in Grids" style="display: none">
        <div id="divGrid-{{ $index }}" data-ng-grid="Grid" class="gridStyle"></div>
    </div>
```